# jstl syntax limitation

Tags: java, jstl

I am trying to manually set values of variables using jstl syntax.

```
 <c:set var="var1" value="2"/>  
 <c:set var="var2" value="2"/>
 <c:set var="var3" value="2"/>
 <c:set var="var4" value="2"/>
 <c:set var="var5" value="2"/>
 <c:set var="var6" value="2"/>
```

The above syntax works.. But I am curious as to why the below syntax does not.

```
<c:forEach var="myVar" start="1" end="6">
 <c:set var="Display${myVar}" value="2"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Why cant we set variable names dynamically in jstl unlike other languages. Is there a smarter way?

Comment: Nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a working code example:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<html>
    <%
        Map myMap = new HashMap();
        pageContext.setAttribute("theMap", myMap);
    %>
    <c:set target="${theMap}" property="aKey" value="value for a key" />
    <c:set target="${theMap}" property="otherKey" value="value for other key" />

    Map content: ${theMap}
</html>
```

Result:
[image: result]
This example uses the page context/scope, which is the default. Of course all contexts/scopes available (page, request, session, application) can be used, if needed.